# I'm not able to use express and fetch in web extension

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am trying to build a web extension using some NPM libs such as sqlite3 and express.
I generated a bundle script using browserify and required it in a script tag, but when I open the extension, it shows an error message saying `http.ServerResponse is undefined` (for express) and
`stream is undefined`(for sqlite3)

manifest.json:

```
{

  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "jpfShortener",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "jpfShortener",
    "default_popup": "menu/jpfShortener.html"
},
  "content_security_policy":  "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval'; object-src 'self'",

  "icons": {
    "48": "icons/48.png"
  },

  "permissions": [
    "<all_urls>"
  ],

  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["menu/jpfShortener.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>"]
    }
  ]

}
```

html's head:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>jpfShortener</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jpfShortener.css"/>
    <script src="../bundleScripts/bundle.js" defer></script>
    <script src="../server.js" defer></script> 
    <script src="../short.js" defer></script> 
</head>
```

short.js:

```
document.getElementById("shortbtn").onclick = function() {short()};

function short() {

  var data = { url: document.getElementById("url").value };

  fetch("/addLink", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(data),
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
  })
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(res => {
      console.log(JSON.stringify(res));
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));

  document.getElementById("url").value = "";
  document.getElementById("url").focus();
};
```

server.js:

```
onload = function(){
  console.log("teseeeete");
  const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
  const express = require("express");
  const fs = require("fs");
  const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3").verbose();
  var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

var listener = app.listen("8080", () => {
  console.log(`Your app is listening on port ${listener.address().port}`);
});

const dbFile = "data/jpfshortener.db";
const exists = fs.readFileSync(dbFile);

const db = new sqlite3.Database(dbFile);

...

app.post("/addLink", (req, res) => {

  //some code
  
});

...

};
```

I also tried to bundle my `server.js` and add it to `content_scripts` but it didn't work.

Also, I can't fetch "/addLink", it doesn't find the url. I believe it's because the mozilla and google temporary web extension's service doesn't work like a server, as localhost.

As a normal node app, it works just fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: You're trying to use server-side code in the client. The client (browser) has restrictions on what you can do. For example, you don't have any of the file access capability nodejs typically gives you.

Comment: That means I can't do anything about it?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to make some kind of url shortener? Generally those are dependent on having a server available to at least serve the shortened url and perform the redirect.